# Memory corruption (?) in debug mode

Tags: qt, winapi, dll, mingw, dynamic-linking

I need to use [`GetVolumeInformationW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For reasons uknown, I decided to load `Kernel32.dll` dynamically, resolve function address at runtime… Result is memory corruption problem and some strange side-effects of modifying stack. Though static version works like a charm and I can just stick with it and move on, I want to investigate the matter.

Source code is self-explaining (comment if you need some more information, full version can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/z9PJz8NE)):

```cpp
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QLibrary>
#include <QDir>

static inline QString LAT1(const char *str, const int len = -1) {
    return QString::fromLatin1(str, len);
}

template <typename T>
static inline QByteArray createByteArray(const T *from, const int numElements) {
    return QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(from), sizeof(T) * numElements);
}

// This one resolves functions from Kernel32.dll dynamically and uses standard types.
// (Dynamic linking.)
QByteArray fingerprintDynamic() {
    const uint32_t kMaxPath = 260 + 1;  // MAX_PATH + 1
    wchar_t path[kMaxPath]       = {0};
    wchar_t name[kMaxPath]       = {0};
    wchar_t fileSystem[kMaxPath] = {0};
    uint32_t serial = 0;
    uint32_t maximumComponentLength = 0;
    uint32_t fileSystemFlags = 0;

    QLibrary kernel32("kernel32");
    typedef uint32_t (*fnGetLastError)(void);
    typedef bool (*fnGetVolumeInformationW)(const wchar_t*, wchar_t*, uint32_t, uint32_t*, uint32_t*,
                                            uint32_t*, wchar_t*, uint32_t);
    fnGetVolumeInformationW GetVolumeInformationW = reinterpret_cast<fnGetVolumeInformationW>(kernel32.resolve("GetVolumeInformationW"));
    fnGetLastError GetLastError = reinterpret_cast<fnGetLastError>(kernel32.resolve("GetLastError"));

    if (!GetVolumeInformationW) {
        qWarning(LAT1("GetVolumeInformationW() not resolved: %1").arg(kernel32.errorString()).toLatin1().constData());
        return QByteArray();
    }
    else if (!GetLastError) {
        qWarning(LAT1("GetLastError() not resolved: %1").arg(kernel32.errorString()).toLatin1().constData());
        return QByteArray();
    }

    QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::rootPath()).toWCharArray(path);
    bool apiCall = GetVolumeInformationW(path, name, kMaxPath, &serial, &maximumComponentLength,
                                         &fileSystemFlags, fileSystem, kMaxPath);
    if (!apiCall)
        qWarning(LAT1("GetVolumeInformationW() failed: %1").arg(GetLastError()).toLatin1().constData());

    // At this point, fileSystem is correct and contains
    // L"NTFS"

    // ONLY HAPPENS IN DEBUG MODE
    //
    // After this call memory becomes corrupted. wcslen() is not a problem.
    // And createByteArray<>() is ok too, I believe.
    //size_t len;  // But if I change stack a bit (like uncomment this line),
                   // result will be correct, so I guess it's related to memory offset.
    return createByteArray<wchar_t>(fileSystem, wcslen(fileSystem));
}

void print(const QByteArray &bytes) {
    qDebug() << QString::fromWCharArray(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(bytes.constData()));
    qDebug() << bytes.size() << "bytes" << bytes.toHex();
    qDebug() << "";
}

int main(int, char**)
{    
    qDebug() << "dynamic";
    print(fingerprintDynamic());

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
// this is DEBUG build
dynamic 
"(?(" 
8 bytes "280052f828000400"

// this is RELEASE build
// (same with `size_t len` uncommenented before `return` in DEBUG)
dynamic 
"NTFS" 
8 bytes "4e00540046005300"
```

**The question is**: what is the reason of such behaviour? where's my mistake is hiding?

I'm using `g++.exe (GCC) 4.4.0`, `Qt 4.8.1` and `Creator 2.5.2`.

Comment: Have you considered using DynamoRIO and Dr. Memory to see which exact location causes it? The claim that `createByteArray<>()` isn't a problem without hard evidence is suspicious ;) ... also consider mudflap (in GCC) if that is available in your build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by a mismatch in the calling convention. `GetVolumeInformationW()` has calling convention `WINAPI` so change the function pointer type to:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *fnGetVolumeInformationW)(const wchar_t*,
                                               wchar_t*,
                                               uint32_t,
                                               uint32_t*,
                                               uint32_t*,
                                               uint32_t*,
                                               wchar_t*,
                                               uint32_t);
```

`WINAPI` is calling convention [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), whereas the default is [`__cdecl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
Note the return type is `BOOL`, and not `bool`.

Comment: Good catch! +1 ... didn't see it

Comment: Yep, looks like you're right. Changed `BOOL` to `int`, `WINAPI` to `__stdcall` and everything works fine (actually, `_stdcall` was enough, but I feel that fixing return type here is a must). Thanks.

Comment: These function pointers should also be marked as `extern "C"`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, why is that? My, possibly mistaken, understanding of `extern "C"` was to disable the C++ name mangling. I don't see why that would be required here. The kernel32.dll is exporting the function whose address is being explicitly looked up.

Comment: @hmjd: strictly speaking `extern "C"` can affect more than name mangling, including calling convention (though it likely doesn't in this case).

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I just checked some C++ code of my own that does similar and `extern "C"` is not used with no issues. Thanks though, I will be checking up.

Comment: @hmjd: I think it's extremely rare that it will cause issues today (particularly on Windows), so it's probably not worth much going back to 'check and fix'. However, I think it's a good idea to get it in the code in the first place since it costs nothing and may help with whatever might happen in the future.